# Having difficulty returning correct format from PHP server side to Vue frontend

Tags: php, json, laravel

My goal is to make an GET axios/ajax call to the database which has records with latitude and longitude and then combine the 2 latitude and longitude for each record into a single JSON object that have the format of `{lat: 20, lng: 20}`. Currently I have this:

```
public function getLocations(Request $request){
    $locations = Location::where('user_id', 1)->get()->toJson();

    return response()->json([
        'locations' => $locations,
        'message' => 'Successfully added locations!'
    ], 201);
}
```

I need to somehow pass an array of json objects. I believe it should look like this:

```
$locations = [   {lat: 10, lng: 10},
    {lat: 11, lng: 11},
    {lat: 12, lng: 12}
]
```

With one JSON object for every record in $locations. The lat and lng are located in $locations. For example $locations->lat and $locations->lng. How would I go about creating such an object that I could use on my frontend?

```
[{"id":40,"user_id":1,"lat":42,"lng":24,"created_at":"2019-01-16 10:14:40","updated_at":"2019-01-16 10:14:40"},
{"id":41,"user_id":1,"lat":43,"lng":25,"created_at":"2019-01-16 10:14:41","updated_at":"2019-01-16 10:14:41"}]
```

Comment: what does `$locations` look like?

Comment: I added the response to my post

Comment: You can use [Laravel APi resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) it's a proper way to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
public function getLocations(Request $request){
    $locations = Location::where('user_id', 1)->get();

    $locationsData= [];
    foreach ($locations  as $location) {
        $locationsData[] = ['lat' => $location->lat, 'lng' => $location->lng];
    }
    return response()->json([
        'locations' => $locationsData,
        'message' => 'Successfully added locations!'
    ], 201);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, only one line of code:

```
$locations = Location::where('user_id', 1)->get(['lat', 'lng'])->toJson();
```